# Finding the definite integral for the enclosed problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I solve the following integral? 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} re^{\frac{-\lambda r^2}{2}}\mathrm{d}r.$$

Comment: Use a substitution. Put $u=\frac{-\lambda r^2}{2}$, then $\mathrm{d}u=-\lambda r\mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: You should include your own thoughts/work on the problem. If you don't add that, the question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int^\infty_0re^{-\lambda r^2/2}dr&=-1/\lambda\int^\infty_0e^{-\lambda r^2/2}d\frac{-\lambda r^2}{2}\\
&=-1/\lambda \int^\infty_0d\left(e^{-\lambda r^2/2} \right)\\
&=-1/\lambda \left(e^{-\lambda r^2/2} \right)\big|^\infty_0\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help